# Jquery Ajax Insert Extremely Slow

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having a tough time trying to figure out why my onblur, which triggers an AJAX call is taking a long time to finish.  It takes dozens of seconds at times.  It seems the more of the "description" fields I have, the longer it takes.  Can anyone review this code, and tell me if they think I'm missing something?

```
var description;
var id;
$(".description").live('blur',function() {
   var success;
   var dataType;
   $(".dynamic_row,<?php echo $services; ?>").each(function() {
      var row = $(this);
      var id = row.find(".id").val() || 0;
      var description = row.find(".description").val() || "";
      var q = <?php echo $q; ?>;
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'setdescname.php',
         data: {ider:id, descriptionr:description, qr:q},
         success: function(result) {
            if(result.isOk == false)
               alert(result.message);
            },
            dataType: dataType
      });
   });
});
```

`<?php echo $services; ?>` pulls in about 16 names of possible dynamic rows that are activated by a checkbox.  That part works just fine...

This is the code in setdescname.php

```
require_once('include/database.php');

if (!dbConnect()) {
    echo 'Error connecting to database';
    exit;
}

$id = $_POST['ider'];
$description = $_POST['descriptionr'];
$q = $_POST['qr'];

$qry = "UPDATE items SET description = '".$description."' WHERE id = '".$id."'";

$result = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
```

If you think it matters, I have the following earlier in my code.

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```

This was required, because all users will be in IE, and it will cache ajax calls, rendering the addition of new "dynamic" fields without the necessary functionality (bringing back the `mysql_insert_id()` on new adds).

All of this does work, it's just painfully slow...

I would appreciate any advice or suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have `$.ajaxSetup({async:false});`?

Comment: I have to be honest and say I don't remember why i do.  There would have been a reason, but I guess I should try this without?  Would that cause the delay?  The only delay is with the description blur.  Other blurs on other pages work fine.

Comment: Get rid of it. I'm sure you'll notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

For fast need ajax cache and  ajax  async

Ajax Cache

$.ajax({ url: '/?=testDefault',
    data: { 'cache': 'default' }
    });//no timestamp

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$.ajax({ url: '/?=testFalse/',
data: { 'cache': 'false' }
});//yes, a timestamp

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
$.ajax({ url: '/?=testTrue/',
data: { 'cache': 'true' }
}); //no timestamp
```

For Ajax async

```
$.ajax({
          url: "super.php",
          data: "a="+a,
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your solution to send all the data to the script in one single request. There is really no to execute numerous requests (especially since you own the server code).

To get you started:

```
var description;
var id;
var dataBuf = [];
$(".description").live('blur',function() {
   var success;
   var dataType;
   $(".dynamic_row,<?php echo $services; ?>").each(function() {
      var row = $(this);
      var id = row.find(".id").val() || 0;
      var description = row.find(".description").val() || "";
      var q = <?php echo $q; ?>;
      dataBuf.push({"ider" : id, "descriptionr" :description, "qr" :q};
    });

    // now send it all as one request:
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'setdescname.php',
        data: {"data": JSON.stringify(dataBuf)},
        success: function(result) {
        if(result.isOk == false)
            alert(result.message);
        },
        dataType: dataType
    });
});
```

And on the server:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo $row['ider'];
    echo $row['descriptionr'];
    echo $row['qr'];
    // etc.
    // do stuff with data, store in DB
    // for example
}
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

P.s. - even if your requests were to fire asynchronously you would run into performance issues since the number of concurrent XHR requests allowed by browsers is limited to, say, a few.